# How do I nest and/or statements in a CSS media query?

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I want to do a media query that says:

```
only screen and either
    (max-width: 64em) and (min-width: 24em)
        or
    (orientation: landscape)
```

In JavaScript notation, what I want would look like this:

```
if ( screen === true && ( width > 24 && width < 64 ) || orientation === "landscape" )
```

How do I do that? Can I use parentheses? Would it be:

```
<link 
    rel='stylesheet' 
    media='only screen and ( ((max-width: 64em) and (min-width: 24em)) or (orientation: landscape) )' href='style.css' />
```

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

"or" is expressed with a comma separating two or more *entire* media queries; "and" with the `and` keyword *within* each media query separating each condition.

Any condition that should hold true for all media queries must be repeated within each query; in your case, that common condition is `only screen`.

Thus:

```
only screen and (max-width: 64em) and (min-width: 24em), 
only screen and (orientation: landscape)
```

If you need to use this media query in a CSS `@media` at-rule rather than an HTML `media` attribute, note that the `@media` token appears only once as it's not technically part of a media query:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 64em) and (min-width: 24em), 
       only screen and (orientation: landscape)
{
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that works! I'll mark it as the answer in 10 minutes when allowed.